# Сортировка объекта со string param

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Всем привет.
Я пытаюсь применить сортировку к своему объекту по полю AccountNumber. Это поле типа String. Но там хранятся как какие-то: **account122, так и 133, 148 и тд**.
И вот мне нужно отсортировать по номерам , вроде такого: **133, 148, account122**. Сейчас почему-то моя сортировка не применяется, можете подсказать, что я не так делаю? P.s. переключатель работает нормально

```
public static IEnumerable<DetailItem> SortAccountBalanceDetailedView(this IEnumerable<DetailItem> reportItems,
            AccountBalanceSortBy accountBalanceSortBy)
        {
            return accountBalanceSortBy switch
            {
                AccountBalanceSortBy.AccountName => reportItems.OrderBy(reportItem =>
                    reportItem.AccountName),
                AccountBalanceSortBy.AccountNumber => reportItems.OrderBy(reportItem =>
                    reportItem.AccountNumber),                                                          //not working
                _ => reportItems
            };
        }
```

Comment: выглядит нормально. мб ты о том что тебе нужно выделить цифры и по ним отсортировать?

Comment: Ваша ошибка не воспроизводится. Убедитесь, что вы вызываете метод с нужным значением `AccountBalanceSortBy`